# Are there any relationships (inequalities) between $|x'Hy|$ and $|x'y|$?

Tags: linear-algebra

where **x**,**y** are $n \times 1$ vectors, **H** is an $n\times n$ hatmatrix (i.e. $H = Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'$).

Comment: This question is probably better suited for math.stackexchange.com than mathoverflow.net. Regardless, for either site, you'll get a more helpful response if you explain what you know and have tried so far. Do you have a example of a hatmatrix $H$? Can you see cases when $|x' H y| < |x'y|$ or $|x' H y| > |x' y|$?

Comment: thanks, actually i have done some simulations before, both cases were observed($|\boldsymbol{x}^\prime\mathbf{H}\boldsymbol{y}|<|\boldsymbol{x}^\prime\boldsymbol{y}|$ and $|\boldsymbol{x}^\prime\mathbf{H}\boldsymbol{y}|>|\boldsymbol{x}^\prime\boldsymbol{y}|$ ), but the former occurs more often, meanwhile, in most cases the difference between these two absolute value is not large but it did different a lot sometimes.

Comment: You'll get very different answers if you ask for a statistical relationship that holds usually for random $x,y$ or an inequality that holds for arbitrary $x,y$. Which are you more interested in?

Comment: in my study, $\mathbf{x}$ is a weight vector with no randomness, while $\mathbf{y}$ is something like residuals, i wonder when $\mathbf{x}^\prime\mathbf{y}$ is small, will $\mathbf{x}^\prime\mathbf{H}\mathbf{y}$ be small too.